# Why my AWS T2.Medium EC2 CPU utilization is at 27% constant, but on running top command shows 100%?

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel

I am running my PHP Laravel application in AWS EC2 instance (T2.Medium, 2 core) through Laravel Forge. For 5 months continuously I am seeing constant CPU utilization of 27% in the AWS console graph. So I tried to check by running "top" command and there I see 100% CPU.

So I want to understand:

```
1. What is my actual CPU utilization out of the 2 cores of T2.medium?
2. In the top command result, forge is utilizing 100% CPU, what is the best way to track what cause the high CPU so that I can lower the CPU utilization.
```

Please note that this EC2 instance is the Application Server. For database I use another instance. It does not have any high CPU utilization.

[image: AWS CPU Utilization Graph]
[image: TOP Command Result]
[image: CPU Credit Usage]
[image: CPU Credit Balance]

Comment: A T2 is only allocated a percentage of a CPU, but you can use the whole CPU for brief periods until you are capped. 25% of a CPU is probably 100% of the CPU power you have bought. When the server is using 100% of a CPU, that's a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

`top` shows the %CPU as a percentage of a **single** core. Hence why sometimes you might see it at a number over 100. If you run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` you should see entries for each core available. So, 100% in the CPU column just means it's using a whole core - if the instance has 4 cores (or 2 cores with hyperthreading) then it's only 25% total.

I like to use `htop` as I think it has better visualisations and display.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that if the process uses multiple threads, its CPU usage (as displayed by `top`) may exceed 100%